# Laravel 5.7 - Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: \"10337e35-8da9-4600-b7de-792398eb6f48\"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to create a database notifcation in Laravel 5.7 and getting this SQL QueryException. My $notifiable variable in the toArray method is the user and this id in the exception: `invalid input syntax for integer: \"10337e35-8da9-4600-b7de-792398eb6f48\"` is the correct id for the user to be notified. I have my notifications table set up in the standard way:

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->morphs('notifiable');
        $table->text('data');
        $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My user table is set up like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

It is set up with a uuid as the primary id. Beyond that, the notification itself has `database` in the via method:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database', 'mail'];
}
```

I've set a couple properties in the toArray method. Nothing complicated. I also tried to manually insert into the notifications table and I can insert an entry with a `notifiable_id` as an int, but not a string/uuid. It's mind boggling to me that the nofiable system would not be set up to allow for uuid's as ids. Maybe it's just a small tweak, but I'm not seeing it out there and figure surely someone else has run into this. Cheers!

Full exception:

```
Object { message: "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: \"0e7cc3d8-bfca-41c1-99f8-6da9e8887465\" (SQL: insert into \"notifications\" (\"id\", \"type\", \"data\", \"read_at\", \"notifiable_id\", \"notifiable_type\", \"updated_at\", \"created_at\") values (f6206d4e-c98f-4ced-a1ee-6a755f073807, App\\Notifications\\BugTransition, {\"bug_id\":\"be14d750-ba6c-4e70-82f7-a36786ff37f4\",\"workflow_state\":\"accepted\"}, , 0e7cc3d8-bfca-41c1-99f8-6da9e8887465, App\\User, 2018-10-22 22:35:54, 2018-10-22 22:35:54))", exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException", file: "/srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php", line: 664,
```

Comment: Have you set `public $incrementing = false; protected $keyType = 'string';` in your mòdels

Comment: No. Would that just be the user model?

Comment: Correction, I did set the `public $incrementing = false;`, but not the keyType.

Comment: In both models (and all others that have a string key).

Comment: That didn't have an effect. Do I need to create a notification eloquent model just to set those on there?

Comment: Please post the whole error message (including the query).

Comment: I'll add it above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `notifiable_id`. `$table->morphs('notifiable');` creates an integer column, but you are trying to store a string.

You have to create the columns (and the index) yourself:

```php
$table->string('notifiable_type');
$table->string('notifiable_id');
$table->index(['notifiable_type', 'notifiable_id']);
```

Comment: And that's the case anytime you want to store a notifiable_type with a uuid? Kinda dumb hah. Thanks!